# How to invoke API which is returning zip file and store the zip to local

Tags: zip

I have a use case where I need to invoke a GET API. Its is returning zip file.
I need to store the zip to my local disk (for example Desktop). I started with this, but no clue on how to continue.

```
RestTemplate templ = new RestTemplate();
byte[] downloadedBytes = templ.getForObject("https:localhost:8080/zip", byte[].class);
```

Can someone please suggest?